# Starting Keycloak server through standalone.sh on different address to localhost

Tags: keycloak

I'm currently building an application where I'm using Keycloak through Docker for ldap authentication.

I want to run some commands such as setting sslRequired=None and enabling metrics as part of my CICD flow for non production testing vm's. (My CICD flow goes through around 3 different VMs before production)

To do this, in my keycloak Dockerfile, I've setup an admin user through the `add-user-keycloak.sh` script and then run `/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh & sleep 20 &&` to start the server. I then run the various admin configuration commands I need. This works fine on locally, however when I run this on any of my testing VM's it doesn't work.

I think this is because when I try to login to any of my testing VM's admin console with the following command

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://$my_external_vm/auth --realm master --user admin --password password
```

it has started the standalone keycloak server on localhost and so the `$my_external_vm` variable is not valid

I've tried setting the -b flag while running standalone.sh, passing in `$my_external_vm` however when I do this, my server doesn't even start up as it is an `"invalid address"`

How do I go about starting my keycloak server on $my_external_vm instead of localhost so that I can get through the described issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the server with both flags: "./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0"